# bootstrap 2.3.2 modal & jquery 1.7.1 How to get the data attribute or id of a clicked element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, click

For some reason I am forced to use bootstrap 2.3.2 modal with jquery 1.7.1.
I have the following code for three conference rooms. 
When I click an element, a modal popup correctly appears but I am failing to get the info of the clicked element in order to display the appropriate info in the modal.

```
<div class="room" id="RM1" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM1<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM2" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM3<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM3" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM4<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>

<div id="my_modal" class="modal fade top10" role="dialog" style="z-index:100000 !important;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:rgb(44,106,159);">
                <button type="button" class="close" style="font-size:38px;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title shadow-heavy" style="color:white" name="modal_title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div name="modal_text"></div>
                <div name="modal_Img"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script:
It is fired, the modal is enabled but I can not the element's info.

```
<script>
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
var rmID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-rm-id');
console.log(rmID); --> undefined

var rmID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
console.log(rmID); --> undefined

var rmID = $(e.target).attr('id');
console.log(rmID); --> my_modal

var rmID = $(e.target).attr('data-rm-id');
console.log(rmID); --> undefined

var rmID = $(e.target).data('rm-id');
console.log(rmID); --> undefined
```

Thanks

Comment: I really don't know how `e.relatedTarget` is going to give you the clicked element but, why don't you get the clicked element's info INSIDE its click handler, like this `$('.room').click(function(){$(this)});`?

Comment: I am confused because the above method with bootstrap 3.x and later version of jquery works.
I thought something and confirmed...
I changed adding the `data-rm-id` in the form 
`<div id="my_modal" ... data-rm-id="test">` 
and from the 
`$(e.target).attr('data-rm-id') and $(e.target).data('rm-id');`
I got response --> test.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 2.3.2 doesn't have `event.relatedTarget`, this feature added after version 3.0.0.

3.0.0 demo:

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id')
  console.log(id)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="room" id="RM1" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM1<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM2" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM3<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM3" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM4<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>

<div id="my_modal" class="modal fade top10" role="dialog" style="z-index:100000 !important;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:rgb(44,106,159);">
        <button type="button" class="close" style="font-size:38px;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title shadow-heavy" style="color:white" name="modal_title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div name="modal_text"></div>
        <div name="modal_Img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a workaround to solve the issue in 2.3.2.

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data('relatedTarget')
  var relatedTaret = $(id)[0]
  console.log(id)
  console.log(relatedTaret)
})

$('.room').on('click',function(){
  var id = "#" + $(this).attr('id')
  var target = $(this).data('target')
  $(target).data('relatedTarget', id)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="room" id="RM1" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM1<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM2" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM3<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM3" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal" data-rm-id="RM1">Room RM4<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>

<div id="my_modal" class="modal fade top10" role="dialog" style="z-index:100000 !important;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:rgb(44,106,159);">
        <button type="button" class="close" style="font-size:38px;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title shadow-heavy" style="color:white" name="modal_title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div name="modal_text"></div>
        <div name="modal_Img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was using bootstrap.js 2.3.2. I changed to 3.0.0 as in your code. I did apply your suggestions but no change. I still can not get the id of the clicked room.
Also .room was not fired. Checked with an alert() in my code.

Comment: I update the demo for 3.0.0 to get the id of the clicked `.room`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure and used an `RMclick` function, which calls the modal show, and used a "public variable" to pass the data:

```
<div class="room" id="RM1" onclick="RMclick('RM1')">Room RM1<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM2" onclick="RMclick('RM2')">Room RM2<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>
<div class="room" id="RM3" onclick="RMclick('RM3')">Room RM3<i class="far fa-map iconMap"></i></div>

<div id="my_modal" class="modal fade top10" role="dialog" style="z-index:100000 !important;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:rgb(44,106,159);">
                <button type="button" class="close" style="font-size:38px;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title shadow-heavy" style="color:white" name="modal_title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div name="modal_text"></div>
                <div name="modal_Img"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


function RMclick(par){
    rmID=par;
    $('#my_modal').modal('show');
}


$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log(rmID); 
    ...
    ...

    switch (rmID) {
        case 'RM1':
            var modal_rm_name="RM1";
            var modal_text="<p class='mapLevel'>Ground Level</p><hr>";
            break;
        case 'RM2':
    ...

    $(this).find('h3[name="modal_title"]').html(modal_rm_name);
    $(this).find('div[name="modal_text"]').html(modal_text);
    $(this).find('div[name="modal_Img"]').html(img);
});
```